# Can't remove icon from gnome panel by Alt+right click or Windows+Alt+right click?

Tags: gnome-panel

I have read some questions about how to remove icon from gnome panel, I try to hold Alt and right click or Windows+Alt and right click but not menu display!
I use Ubuntu 12.0

Comment: well, after some weeks, I finally solved this problem. There two ways: 1. You can login with Gnome (no effects) and you can use Alt+right click or Alt+windows+right click; 2. You can using command: gconftool –recursive-unset /apps/panel 
=> rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
 
=> pkill gnome-panel
Or you can use other commands that similarly! good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>SUPER</kbd> then right click on the icon you want to remove.

In the context menu that follows from your click, you will see 2 options, 'move' or 'remove from panel'; and these are your options.